# Curly Capital M symbol in Latex

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I am looking for the name and latex code for this symbol.

[image]

Comment: `\mathcal{M}` according to http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: See also [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/134144)

Comment: Consider the mathrsfs package and \mathscr{M} (or another font that offers script variants).